# How to implement OAuth with Gentics Mesh?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito, gentics-mesh

I am attempting to use AWS Cognito to implement authentication in Gentics Mesh. I expect to need to create a plugin in order to support role mapping but for now I just want to be able to authenticate with a user from Cognito. I downloaded the JWT file from Cognito and added it to the public-keys config, but I am not sure where to go from here. How do I tell the Gentics server to use my Cognito instance for Auth?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable because Gentics Mesh supports OpenID Connect (https://getmesh.io/docs/authentication/#_oauth2_oidc).

You can set it up using both User Pool with hosted UI and Identity Pool. You can use this documentation as a starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html